# COMPOSERでのCAKEPHPのインストールをしようとしてSSL系のエラーを招いている

Tags: composer

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
現在私の開発端末で生じている事象は、
https://qiita.com/dora_kou/items/c9c2f7d8d53303ee1aab
で掲載された記事同様（全く同じエラーメッセージではない）の解釈ですが、自身の応用能力・読解力がなくこちらから解決策を導けない状況でこまっています。

どなたか現在のこの状況を脱却する手立てを、教えていただけないでしょうか？
コマンドプロンプトで、何かの操作をするのでしょうか
（ちなみにHTTP_PROXYという環境変数に、ID・パスワードの認証情報を含めたProxyServer定義を事前に対応しています。これがなかった状況では、そのようなホストは不明です、というエラーを招いていました。この対応をとった後、参考にさせて頂いた記事に記載のあったURLへアクセスして、cacert.pemというファイルを一応に入手しています。現在デスクトップに貼り付けています。）

やはりProxyServerを介してCOMPOSERを動作させることは相応の覚悟が必要なのですかね．．．
（昨日なんとかCOMPOSER自体を当該端末にセットアップをできたものの）

IEのオプションを追記
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md とりあえず公式にある`composer diagnose`をためしたらどのような情報が出ますか？あと可能ならエラーメッセージは画像ではなく文字でコピペすると回答の際引用検索しやすいです。

Comment: @keitaro_so いつも大変お世話になっております。
ご見解をありがとうございます。早速当方の開発端末Windows7（x86）で
コマンドプロンプトより以下を実行してみました。


>php composer.phar diagnose
Could not open input file: composer.phar


ご見解に対し、異なった確認をしているようであれば、
お手間ですがご指摘をお願い申し上げます。

Comment: composer.pharがないと言われていますね。windowsにインストールComposerをインストールしているのであれば、パスが通っているはずですので、質問文の画像中と同じように`composer diagnose`でいけるはずです。もう一度お試しください。

Comment: @keitaro_so 実行致しました、全文でありませんが以前貼り付けた内容同様のエラーを招いています。[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed ...

Comment: proxyを通してSSLのエラーが発生しているようですね。proxyサーバ側にSSLに関する制約等はありますか？

Comment: 社内の人間に確認しました。ブラウザ側（IE）の設定で、後継のTLSを利用している、と伝えられました。
この辺りを、一時的にいじれば　どうにかなるなら良いのですが。
本文にもIEのそのあたりの設定部分を添付しましたが（すみません）
SSL 2.0を使用する/SSL 3.0を使用する　双方OFF
TLS 1.1を使用する/TLS 1.1の使用/TLS 1.2の使用がONの状態です。
引き続きご見解を頂けましたら幸いです。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76535/discussion-between-keitaro-so-and-saya24)しましょう。

Comment: システム環境変数とユーザ環境変数、2パターンがあるようですが当方が設定したのはシステム環境変数です。
またそれらは、HTTP_PROXYとHTTPS_PROXYの２種類であり、双方の変数名は大文字です。
変数値はhttp://～とhttps://～という記述をしています。